# Angular project forget password send email link not working in Chrome browser (First time only. Second time working as expected)

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I am developing an angular6 application and deployed with a domain lime "www.mydomain.com/".

All the routings are working fine like "www.mydomain.com/dashboard", "www.mydomain.com/products", etc.,

The problem is we have a change password to link it's like "www.mydomain.com/mga/sps/authsvcurn:ibm:security:authentication/changePassword". (The link is sending OTP mail to our mail id which one is used to login the application and waiting to update OTP)

I used the link to redirect change the password. But it will not redirect it's going to the home page only "www.mydomain.com/" because of routing the same domain.

### update

The issue is happening the only **first-time chrome browser only**. When I login the first time click the "Change Password" button the link is triggered but after few seconds redirecting to the home page.

Second time if I click the same button the link is redirecting to the correct page (change password URL page).

How can I resolve this problem? Please help me out.

Here is the code:

### my-profile.component.html

`<a (click)="changePassword()">Change Password</a>`

### my-profile.component.ts

`changePassword() {
    window.location.href = 'www.mydomain.com/mga/sps/authsvcurn:ibm:security:authentication/changePassword';
  }`

Comment: Can you also shows the paths in the routing file? Especially the one that should match the changePassword component?

Comment: Angular doesn't have any component for "Change password". The link is different like some external URL given by other team.

Comment: Open the network debugger and check if there is any redirection or error. Is your `mga/sps/...` page an angular route?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `changePassword()` method to:

```
<a (click)="changePassword($event)">Change Password</a>


changePassword(event) {
    window.location.href = 'www.mydomain.com/mga/sps/authsvcurn:ibm:security:authentication/changePassword';
    event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Alternatively you can use `window.open`:

```
// _blank is optional, it opens the url in a new window. 
// You can omit if you want to navigate from the current window.

window.open("https://google.com/","_blank");
```

**UPDATE**

Other points that can help you debugging:

1 - Enable routes tracing (in `app-routing.module.ts`):

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- for debugging purposes only
    )
]
```

This will print on the DevTools console all the routes Angular visits.
 This provides you with some insights why the first time is not working.

What I might guess, is that the target route or the needed parameters are not properly defined and the Angular routing cannot match it with any configured path, redirecting to /home.

2 - If a Stackblitz solution is not possible, can you provide all your routes involved and all the relevant parameters involved when you trigger the redirection?

Comment: It's not working. After login the application first time click the "Change Password" button it's redirect to home page but again click the button it's redirecting to the correct URL (forget password link)

Comment: I updated my answer. In case even the new method is not working on your side, I would suggest to provide the routing paths and the other parts of code involved or create  a stackBlitz demo.

Comment: I tried but not working for some reason I am not able to create stackBlitz

Comment: I updated my answer with one hint and the need of more infos.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried the Angular Router?

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

changePassword() {
    this.router.navigate(['/myURL', { myParamName: myParamValue }]);
  }
```

In the target component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

public ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        const myParamValue = params.get('myParamName');
        if (myParamValue) {

        }
    });
}
```